# E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.Rtti.T' and 'MyInterfaceImpl.T' generic

Tags: delphi, generics

I use Delphi 10.3. I have two kind of method implementation for converting enumeration types back and fort to string. This is not the real implementation just two variants for the essence of the service:

Case 1:

```
TMyClass = class
  private
    ctx : TRTTIContext;
  public
    function asString<T>( const value_ : T ) : string;
    function fromString<T>( const value_ : string ) : T;
end;

function TMyClass.asString<T>( const value_ : T ) : string;
var
  rttiType : TRTTIType;
begin
  rttiType := ctx.getType( typeInfo( T ) );
  if ( rttiType.typeKind = tkEnumeration ) then
  begin
    result := TRTTIEnumerationType( rttiType ).getName( value_ );
  end;
end;

function TMyClass.fromString<T>( const value_ : string ) : T;
var
  rttiType : TRTTIType;
begin
  rttiType := ctx.getType( typeInfo( T ) );
  if ( rttiType.typeKind = tkEnumeration ) then
  begin
    result := TRTTIEnumerationType( rttiType ).getValue( value_ );
  end;
end;
```

Case2:

```
IMyInterface<T> = interface
  ['{C03754B7-2225-4EB5-97C1-9820B3D1EBAD}']
  function asString( const value_ : T ) : string;
  function fromString( const value_ : string ) : T;
end;

TMyInterfaceImpl<T> = class ( TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface<T> )
  private
    ctx : TRTTIContext;
  public
    function asString( const value_ : T ) : string;
    function fromString( const value_ : string ) : T;
end;

function TMyInterfaceImpl<T>.asString( const value_ : T ) : string;
var
  rttiType : TRTTIType;
begin
  rttiType := ctx.getType( typeInfo( T ) );
  if ( rttiType.typeKind = tkEnumeration ) then
  begin
    result := TRTTIEnumerationType( rttiType ).getName( value_ );
  end;
end;

function TMyInterfaceImpl<T>.fromString( const value_ : string ) : T;
var
  rttiType : TRTTIType;
begin
  rttiType := ctx.getType( typeInfo( T ) );
  if ( rttiType.typeKind = tkEnumeration ) then
  begin
    result := TRTTIEnumerationType( rttiType ).getValue( value_ );
  end;
end;
```

The `TRTTIEnumeration.GetName/GetValue` works fine in `TMyClass` implementation but does not compile in the `TMyInterfaceImpl<T>`:

`E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.Rtti.T' and 'MyInterfaceImpl.T'`

`E2531 Method 'GetValue' requires explicit type argument(s)`

But I want to implement this service as an interface. Is there any solution to do that with the `TMyInterfaceImpl<T>`? The generic type parameterized methods are not allowed in Interfaces. (`procedure foo<T>( const value_ : T );`)

Comment: What is your IMyInterface declaration? Your TMyClass fails to compile with same error. You need to use getValue<T> and getName<T> in call.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar IMyInterface<T> just declares `asString` and `fromString` as like in the implementation. I put it into the code example. You are right! I just tested `TMyClass.asString` with `getName` with success and I assumed '`TMyClass.fromString` compiles as well. But it cause the same error message like in the interfaced implementation. It gets stranger and stranger. One TRTTIEnumerationType method call works, other one does not.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Convert your getValue<T> and getName<T> comment to an answer and I will accept it. Surprisingly I should call `TRTTIEnumerationTypee.getName<T>( value_ )` and not `TRTTIEnumerationTypee.getName( value_ );`. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetName` and `GetValue` class functions in `TRTTIEnumerationType` are parameterized functions:

```
class function GetName<T{: enum}>(AValue: T): string; reintroduce; static;
class function GetValue<T{: enum}>(const AName: string): T; static;
```

You need to add `T` when you call them `GetName<T>(...)` and `GetValue<T>(...)`

```
function TMyInterfaceImpl<T>.asString( const value_ : T ) : string;
var
  rttiType : TRTTIType;
begin
  rttiType := ctx.getType( typeInfo( T ) );
  if ( rttiType.typeKind = tkEnumeration ) then
  begin
    result := TRTTIEnumerationType( rttiType ).getName<T>( value_ );
  end;
end;

function TMyInterfaceImpl<T>.fromString( const value_ : string ) : T;
var
  rttiType : TRTTIType;
begin
  rttiType := ctx.getType( typeInfo( T ) );
  if ( rttiType.typeKind = tkEnumeration ) then
  begin
    result := TRTTIEnumerationType( rttiType ).getValue<T>( value_ );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was careless at the method call. Reconsider it, it seems logical to define the Enum type. The TRTTIEnumerationType does not define it by itself.